# What's the best way to start validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just curious as to if there would be any performance gain with doing

```
if (variable !== undefined)
```

in comparison with

```
if (variable.length)
```

I see both a lot but they occur to me as the same.

Comment: you'll get an error if `variable` is undefined and you try to access `.length`.

Comment: They do totally different things?!

Comment: If they are used for different purposes, I would like to know please. Thanks

Comment: @SeongLee: Well, the first one compares it with the `undefined` value, while the second checks whether its (assuming it to be an object) `.length` is truthy.

Comment: This depends on how `variable` is defined, whether it can be undefined, and what value you want to test for it to be. The two cases test for two very different things.

Comment: one is duck typing, the other is a strict comparison. note that "" would be true for the first and false for the second, which is why folks are usually more explicit when robustness counts/matters. you may also want to consider if(variable!=null), which avoids both undefined and it's dom-equivalent, null.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Not sure what the downvotes are for as I believe anyone new to programming will take some knowledge from this and what some of you might consider as basic may not be the case to some.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `if (variable !== undefined)`.  As stated by @NG. in the above comments, the alternative will throw an error if `variable` **is undefined**.

**There shouldn't be any performance difference at all.**  If anything, speed and accuracy could be better on the `!==` more than the `.length`.

It takes slightly more CPU power to calculate the `.length` than it does to check if a `variable` is **not undefined**.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Using JSLitmus.js**

43977 Ops/sec for `if (variable !== undefined)`

43703 Ops/sec for `if (variable.length)`

There is no different on performance, but like mentioned on the comments - using the `.length` will cause an error if the variable is undefined.

Hope it's helped.

Comment: What *values* did you use in `variable` for these benchmarks? Also, it hardly makes sense to compare their performance as they obviously do different things.

Comment: Yeah they does different things, but the OP asked for this. the variable has a string ('test')